# IF / COUNTIF statement to provide an overall outcome based on multiple options

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, countif

I have hit a bit of a wall and it is probably an easy fix for someone. I am trying to place an overall grade on excel based on previous entries.
Range is E73:E88
Possible outcomes on those ranges are PASS / N/A / DEVELOPING / 0.

I am trying to figure out a code to show:
if all entries are 0 or N/A then the overall outcome is NOT GRADED.
if the entries are all PASS or a mix of PASS or N/A then the overall outcome is PASS
if any of the entries have DEVELOPING then the overall outcome is DEVELOPING.

I have been using IF and COUNTIF formula but I cant seem to find the correct outcome so I am unsure if I am using the correct method.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(E73:E88,"DEVELOPING"),"DEVELOPING",IF(COUNTIF(E73:E88,"PASS"),"PASS",IF(COUNTIF(E73:E88,"0"),"NOT GRADED","PASS")))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Will you have the mix of `PASS or N/A` and the mix of `0 or N/A`?
Or you may also have 0 and PASS mix? In other words, will you have the list of all entries mentioned in one column

Comment: Good question @NoobVB. I suppose that if a 0 is involved anywhere I would want the outcome as NOT GRADED.

Comment: Is it resolved now?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ifna function:

```
=ifna(if(COUNTIF(E73:E88,"DEVELOPING"),"DEVELOPING",if(COUNTIF(E73:E88,"PASS"),"PASS", "not-graduated")),"not-graduated" )
```